# ConcurrentModificationException but not removing anything from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, exception

So I'm making a game and every 5 seconds there must spawn an enemy, know when I run my application it throws an exception '`ConcurrentModificationException`'.
This is a part of my code:

```
private void tick() {

    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              enemyY = enemyYRand.nextInt(6);
              enemy.add(new Enemy(enemyY, 10, enemyImg));
          }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if (player.y > getHeight() - playerImg.getHeight(null)) {
        player.setY(-10);
    }
    if (player.y < 0) {
        player.setY(+10);
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(Enemy enemys : enemy) {
        enemys.render(g);
    }
    player.render(g);
}
```

First the tick method get's called then paintComponent method.

This is the output:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at _47b3n.spaceinvaders.framework.Main.paintComponent(Main.java:141)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5223)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5171)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4982)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:824)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace? 

By the way, I suggest you reading this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks, edited it

Comment: Can you tell us where you are calling paintComponent? Is it your own method?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException`s can be associated with *any* modification to a collection, additions as well as removals.

Comment: @svasa paintComponent is the method you override in AWT/Swing to paint your own components.

Comment: I know, I thought you somehow weren't calling in GUI thread. If not make sure it is run in SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have 2 threads each operating on an `ArrayList` at the same time.

One of them is in the event dispatch thread, where `paintComponent` is called.  You are using an enhanced for loop, which uses an `Iterator` internally.  This iterator is what is throwing the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You are modifying the `ArrayList` in the `tick` method, in some other thread, when you call `enemy.add(new Enemy(enemyY, 10, enemyImg));`.

The `Iterator` noticed that the `ArrayList` was modified and threw the exception.  When you are displaying the enemies, it is necessary to have a consistent view of your `ArrayList`.

Synchronize access to this `ArrayList` on some object (maybe even `enemy` itself) by enclosing read and write operations on this `ArrayList` in `synchronized` blocks.  That means that only one of these blocks can be executing at the same time.

```
synchronized (enemy) {
    enemy.add(new Enemy(enemyY, 10, enemyImg));
}
```

and

```
synchronized (enemy) {
    for(Enemy enemys : enemy) {
        enemys.render(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Other options for completeness: use a data structure that is inherently thread-safe, such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. Or wrap your list using `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!